# Read MS WORD file page by page

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating an C# WPF application to copy MS Word file page by page and paste it in an Ms Excel file.

I found the following link to read a whole MS Word file.

http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/5cd1b721-9b94-4ea0-bd6e-2bb157401069/

But i wanted to read page by page, please help me anybody.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work after opening the document as in the article; it's from memory/docs, so milage may vary :)

```cs
object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
var document = application.ActiveDocument;
Word.WdStatistic stat = Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages; 
int num =  aDoc.ComputeStatistics(stat, ref missing);    // Get number of pages

for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Go to page "i"
            .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage, missing, missing, i.ToString());
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection           // Select whole page
            .GoTo(WdGoToItem.wdGoToBookmark, missing, missing, "\\page");
    document.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();   // Copy to clipboard

    // Do whatever you want with the selection
}
```